# Elastic Beanstalk in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I made and deployed my Django application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It has a connection to a Postgres DB in RDS, through the EBS console.

When I click `configuration` -> `network` in EBS, I see: "*This environment is not part of a VPC.*"

**How can I make it a part of a VPC?** Thanks!

NOTE: very new to this ;)

Comment: Have you read the [docs on EB in VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html)? If yes, what's unclear or why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin I tried looking at them, but, just given how new I am to this stuff, I couldn't really understand it. I went to VPC Management, selected ```VPC with Public and Private Subnets``` but didn't know what to set ```Elastic IP Allocation ID```. I followed this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

Comment: As @stefansundin you will be already in default VPC. Do you want to move to custom VPC with private subnets where rds will be placed?

Comment: @Marcin yes, I want the RDS to only be able to be accessed by other entities in the VPC.

Comment: You have external RDS, or created as part of the EB environment?

Comment: @Marcin I created it in the EB Console, by going ```configuration``` -> ```database```. Not sure if this means "as a part of the EB environment", but I assume so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by @stefansundin  you can't move existing EB into a custom VPC. You have to create new one.

These are **general steps** to consider:

1. Create a **custom VPC with public and private subnets** as described in the docs: [VPC with public and private subnets (NAT)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html). NAT is needed for instances and rds in private subnet to communicate with internet, but no inbound internet traffic will be allowed. This ensures that your instances and rds are not accessible from the outside.
2. Create new **RDS, external** to EB. This is good practice as otherwise the lifetime of your RDS is coupled with EB environment. Starting point is the following AWS documentation: [Launching and connecting to an external Amazon RDS instance in a default VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/rds-external-defaultvpc.html)
3. Create **new EB environment** and ensure to customize its settings to use the VPC. Pass the RDS endpoint to the EB instances using environmental variables. Depending on how you want to handle password to the RDS, there are few options, starting from using  environmental variables (low security) through [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) (free) or [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) (not free).

Setting this all up correctly can be difficult for someone new to AWS. But with patience and practice it can be done. Thus, I would recommend with **starting with default VPC**, as you have now. Then once you are comfortable with how to work with external RDS, think on creating custom VPC as described.

Comment: Marcin, thank you for your response! A few small questions. 1) So should I leave ```NAT``` blank when creating the VPC? 2) When creating the external RDS, do I need to add it to the VPC? 3) I want to be the most secure as possible, thus will want to use SSM or Secrets. Which do you recommend?

Comment: @JJT You can add NAT later. This will require setting up route tables as shown in the docs. When you create RDS, you have to ensure that you create new subnet group, where you can specify private subnets of your custom VPC. SSM is free, but secrets provides automated rotation of credentials to RDS. Thus probably secrets would be better as they are specially designed to work with rds.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Just to be clear, what does automated rotation mean 

Comment: @JJT Automated changing of rds credentials on periodic basis. More [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html).

Comment: Makes sense, just accepted this answer. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @JJT Thanks and no problem. Give it a go, and if get stuck, feel free to make new question:-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to recreate the Elastic Beanstalk environment and pick the VPC during the creation. It is not possible to move an existing environment into a VPC.

But, unless you have access to [EC2-Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html), the EC2 servers that were launched are already be in a VPC. They are just in [the *default* VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html). But as far as Elastic Beanstalk is concerned, it seems oblivious to this.

I am not sure if there are any features that are exclusively available to VPC environments. My suggestion is to try to use your current environment, and if you happen to recreate the environment later for some other reason, then you can try picking a VPC and see if it offers anything new.

Comment: I see, looking at this: ```https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html```, I see that I can use ```--vpc```. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: I have tried `--vpc`, but I just wanted to try it out. My app does not require a VPC for anything, so I switched back to a non-VPC environment.